Changing the Rstudio document outline defaults
all my
# +----------+
# | HEADINGS | ####
# +----------+

do not show up in the RStudio outline anymore because now they would need to be
# +----------+
# HEADINGS | ####
# +----------+

Is there a way to change this back or do I have to re-write every file I wrote in the last 10 years? And if they decide to change it to
# +----------+
# HEADINGS ####
# +----------+

In the next update, how can I make sure that doesn't affect me?

I wonder is that a bug? The definition of a code section, as I always understood was that: any comment line which includes at least four trailing dashes (-), equal signs (=), or pound signs (#) automatically creates a code section. What rstudio version are you using?

Can you not reproduce it? For me, as soon as the first commented out character is a "|", the heading disappears from the outline. I just updated.

I am on version 2023.06.1 and its not an issue. If its happening on a new version I suspect it might be a bug.

yes, 2024.04.2 It did happen after an update, I just assumed it was a feature.

I submitted a bug report and it was already fixed. Should be in a future update:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14877#issuecomment-2217539922

I'm not sure you can protect yourself from breaking changes, but you could run a regex against your scripts as you use them so as not to have to rewrite each heading individually.
Note, the formatting has already has been changed to the last example.
Contents of my_script.R (Old Headings)
# +----------+
# | rnorm() example | ####
# +----------+

x <- rnorm(10)

# +----------+
# | runif() example | ####
# +----------+

y <- runif(10)


Rewrite Code
src <- readLines("my_script.R")
gsub("(# )\\| (.*) \\|( ####)", "\\1\\2\\3", src) |>
  writeLines("my_script_rehead.R")

Contents of my_script_rehead.R (New Headings)
# +----------+
# rnorm() example ####
# +----------+

x <- rnorm(10)

# +----------+
# runif() example ####
# +----------+

y <- runif(10)

